# Extra matching when using findText() for multiple ocurrences

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I am trying to find multiple katakana words (a bunch of letters inside a Unicode range) in a japanese document using findText with the following code:

```
function highlightKatakana() {

  var katakana = "[\u30A0-\u30FF]+";

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bodyElement = doc.getBody();
  var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(katakana); 

  while (searchResult != null) {
    var thisElementText = searchResult.getElement().asText();
    Logger.log(thisElementText.getText());
    Logger.log("From " + searchResult.getStartOffset() + " to " + searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive());
    searchResult = bodyElement.findText(katakana, searchResult);
  }
}
```

For some reason I don't get, when searching for the next occurrence, it is starting at the last character of the previous ocurrence, and therefore it matches again as a one character word.

Here is an example from the log, it should match only once:

**キンメダイ**の切り身に包丁目を入れ（火通りをよくし、味をしみ込みやすくするため）、熱湯をかけてすぐに氷水にとる（霜降り）。
From 0 to 4

キンメダ**イ**の切り身に包丁目を入れ（火通りをよくし、味をしみ込みやすくするため）、熱湯をかけてすぐに氷水にとる（霜降り）。
From 4 to 4

Since searchResult is a RangeElement with only get methods, What should be the correct way to use the findText(searchPattern, from) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug here, and the `RangeElement` does not move the index to the end + 1 position.

You could try to work around this by "eating up" the character with another search (`[\s\S]` should advance by 1 character):

```
while (searchResult != null) {
    var thisElementText = searchResult.getElement().asText();
    Logger.log(thisElementText.getText());
    Logger.log("From " + searchResult.getStartOffset() + " to " + searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive());
    searchResult = bodyElement.findText("[\s\S]", searchResult); // <= HERE
    searchResult = bodyElement.findText(katakana, searchResult);
  }
```

[image]

Or use JS (similar to what Tim suggests):

```
var katakana = /[\u30A0-\u30FF]+/g;
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
while ((m=katakana.exec(doc.getBody().getText())) !== null) {
  Logger.log("Matched: " + m[0] + ", from " + m.index + " to " + katakana.lastIndex);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var re = /[\u30A0-\u30FF]+/g; 
var str = 'キンメダイの切り身に包丁目を入れ（火通りをよくし、味をしみ込みやすくするため）、熱湯をかけてすぐに氷水にとる（霜降り）。';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    alert(m);
}
```

Output:

```
キンメダイ
```